# How to use getCode() in EventHandler

Tags: java, javafx-8

How I can use `getcode()` in `handle` method?

I want to understand which key is pressed.

Note: *I do not want to Change "Event" to "KeyEvent" in handle method*

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  Scene scene;
  Group root = new Group();

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    scene = new Scene(root, 600, 800);
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(this);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(Event event) {
    if (event.getEventType().equals(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)) {
      System.out.println("You Pressing : " /* required code here */ );
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only choice is a cast

```
System.out.println("You Pressing : " + ((KeyEvent) event).getCode() );
```

`getCode` is a method on `KeyEvent` only, so you must access it through a reference of that static type.  You cannot use an `Event` reference to accomplish that.  If you really wanted to you could use reflection but that would be far more messy and hackish than the downcast.